# How do I style an option of a select dropdown in Angular

Tags: css, angular

The first option in my dropdown is an empty value and is selectable. How do I make it grey?

This is what I've tried unsuccessfully based on other questions:

`<ng-option [value]="''" [ngStyle]="{ 'color':'#999999' }">{{placeholder}}</ng-option>`

`<ng-option [value]="''" style="color:#999999">{{placeholder}}</ng-option>`

I'm using Angular 9 but this functionality obviously hasn't changed for a couple of versions.

Comment: Do you want to disable the option? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp

Comment: No, it just needs to be formatted grey, so the user can clear one field without clicking the [Clear] button that clears all the fields.

Comment: @dataphile This is about styling an option, not formatting the content, maybe you bettere change the title

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[style.backgroundColor]="'#999999'"` or `style.backgroundColor="#999999"`.

`color` won't work because it refers to the font color of the text, which is probably empty in your case.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-first-option-grey

Comment: Nope, the content is there and it’s the text color I want to change.

Comment: Well, change `backgroundColor` to `color` and it will change the text color, simple as that.